# what happens memory-wise when putExtra() is called?

Tags: android, android-intent, memory, memory-management

In my android application I have an large ArrayList of objects (more than 100), and I'm passing this ArrayList from activity to activity via the intents, using the putExtra(key,value)  function. What exactly happens memory wise when I do such thing, does the ArrayList gets copied so now it occupies twice the memory it needed at first? or it jst get referenced so the space stays the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are passing your `ArrayList`, you are serializing/parceling it. This is called [marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29). On the other end, you are reading these parcels and doing unmarshalling. What it does is basically convert your `ArrayList` to stream that you read on the other end and making a **COPY** of the original.

Comment: It is worth noting that marshalling does not occur until it is needed - calling putExtra does not make a copy until the Bundle is serialised